# Server Email configuration on Cpanel

Tags: email, server, configuration, cpanel

I've create an email address in my Cpanel server, actually when I test,  I can't receive emails (testing with gmail and outlook ), this is the configuration interface I got after create my mail:

[image]

[image]

can anyone explain and help ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should see if the MX records for your domain are properly set to route your emails from your cPanel account.

If they're correct you can take a look at cPanel's Track Delivery (or Mail Delivery) tool to get more information about why the emails aren't being delivered.